# Uneven distribution of shards over the consumer application workers in amazon-kinesis-client-python

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl, amazon-kinesis-client

In the Dynamo table that holds the leases and checkpoint information, I can see that workers have an uneven distribution of shards.
In my case for example - for 256 shards and 41 workers (pods in Kubernetes), the majority have ~6-8 shards assigned, but I also see ~5 workers with only 1-2 shards.

How can I make the distribution more evenly? is there some configuration I can change for it?

This causes workers to not fully utilize their resources (the workers with the 1-2 shards barely use any CPU and I would rather have another worker with ~6-8 shards than 5 workers with 1-2 shards each).

It is worth mentioning I am using the amazon-kinesis-client-python library.